# What Travis CI environment variable will tell me if secret environment variables are accessible to a current build?

Tags: environment-variables, travis-ci

I'm setting up some tests to be run via Travis CI. I have some secret encrypted environment variables containing AWS credentials. According to [Travis's documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-encrypted-variables-in-.travis.yml), encrypted environment variables aren't available in untrusted builds such as GitHub Pull Requests. I'd like to make it so that if/when an un-trusted build is run, the testing scripts do something different.

The [Environment Variables doc page](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Convenience-Variables) says Travis provides `TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST` in order to say when a build is triggered by a pull request. However, it's not clear to me whether there are other circumstances in which Travis may withhold encrypted environment variables. As it earlier refers to (emphasis mine):

> Encrypted variables are not available to untrusted builds **such as** pull requests coming from another repository.

This suggests to me that there are other builds that Travis would consider untrusted, besides simply Pull Requests.

`TRAVIS_SECURE_ENV_VARS` seems like a better fit, but it seems to be set to `true` when secure variables are **defined**, regardless of whether they are used or not. Will this resolve to `false` if it's done by an untrusted build?

The obvious solution is to of course just check to see if the secret environment variables are defined at all when the code runs. But that's not ideal for my use-case, though it's probably what I'll end up doing if I can't find anything.